# Cordova sqlite plugin android regexp function

Tags: java, android, regex, sqlite, cordova

First of all, thanks for reading and/or answering me!

So, actually I got some troubles using REGEXP with the sqlite plugin from Brody (this one: https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage )

I know usually REGEXP is not embedded with sqlite as a default usable function, but I saw that it implemented in this plugin, and it's working on ios, but not on Android... (As if the function doesn't even exist at all)

So my question is "Can you help me understand why it's not working? And how can I make it work with this plugin?"

Thank you everybody! :D

My request: "SELECT * FROM ASSETS WHERE id REGEXP '32'"

used in 2 separate ways to test if it was an error generated by how I called the sqlite plugin:

this one:

```
SQLite.exec( db, request, [], function(results) {
        var assets = [];
        for (var i = 0, rows = results.length; i < rows && assets.length < 100; i++) {
            assets.push(results.item(i));
        }
        return callback(assets);
});
```

And this one:

```
var db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: db_name});

db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(request, [], function(tx, result) {
        success(result);
    } function(tx, error) {
        error(error);
    }
});
```

The error: "prepare statement failed with error 1"

Actually tried the regexp sqlite function with a working request, but it's not working on android.

On the C lib for sqlite in the cordova plugin I found a regexp function, tried to make it work, but this is not working for the moment, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

This is what I added in the sqlite c library before building the app:

```
#include <regex.h>

void sqlite_regexp(sqlite3_context* context, int argc, sqlite3_value** values)
{
    int ret;
    regex_t regex;
    char* reg = (char*)sqlite3_value_text(values[0]);
    char* text = (char*)sqlite3_value_text(values[1]);

    if ( argc != 2 || reg == 0 || text == 0) {
        sqlite3_result_error(context, "SQL function regexp() called with invalid arguments.\n", -1);
        return;
    }

    ret = regcomp(&regex, reg, REG_EXTENDED | REG_NOSUB);
    if ( ret != 0 ) {
        sqlite3_result_error(context, "error compiling regular expression", -1);
        return;
    }

    ret = regexec(&regex, text , 0, NULL, 0);
    regfree(&regex);

    sqlite3_result_int(context, (ret != REG_NOMATCH));
}

sqlite3_create_function(*db, "regexp", 2, SQLITE_ANY,0, &sqlite_regexp,0,0)
```

source: http://question.ikende.com/question/2D31373237343132383834

PS: Tell me if I need to add some precisions again. Thanks.

Comment: please post relevant parts of your code. Do you expect, someone will dig it up from linked github?

Comment: Nope, sry, my bad! I'll edit my main post to add some precision. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the C code in the sqlite plugin will not have any effect on the Android version. The Android version is built from Java and uses native sqlite libraries built from https://github.com/liteglue/Android-sqlite-native-driver. It would be possible to add the `sqlite_regexp` function to the C code in https://github.com/liteglue/Android-sqlite-native-driver, rebuild the libraries, and use them with the sqlite plugin but this has not been tested so far.

Comment: Thanks, I understand why it was not working then, I need this function, so I will look at this, thanks for your answer brody! :)

Comment: If you have done this correctly, can you please guide me how to do it? I do want to do it but couldn't find any well-documented solution yet.

Comment: @WaqasAhmedAnsari please ask such questions on the referenced GitHub project (https://github.com/liteglue/Android-sqlite-native-driver) for faster response. To build Android-sqlite-native-driver the first you just have to do make init and then make in a git clone, assuming you have NDK installed. To build a second time you just have to do make.